# Does a continuous-time stochastic process satisfying this evolution equation have the Markov property?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

It is well-known that, for a continuous-time Markov process, the transition probabilities $\mathbf{P} = \mathbb{P}\left[X(t) = j |X(0) = i\right]$ satisfy the following evolution equation:

$$\frac{d\mathbf{P}}{dt} = \mathbf{A}{\mathbf{P}}$$

where $\mathbf{A}$ is a time-independent matrix usually called the generator matrix.

If I were to identify a stochastic process whose transition probabilities evolve according to this equation, would this immediately imply the process possesses the Markov property?

Comment: No, because this says nothing about higher dimensional marginals of the process, for example, about whether $$P(X(2)\in B\mid X(1),X(0))=P(X(2)\in B\mid X(1))$$

Comment: Additional to @Did's comment, if you consider a stochastic differential equation for $X_t$: ${\rm d}X_t=b(X_t)\,{\rm d}t+\sigma(X_t)\,{\rm d}W_t$, where $b$ and $\sigma$ are, say, smooth functions, and $W_t$ denotes the Wiener process, then $X_t$ has the Markov property. However, this does not hold true if ${\rm d}X_t=b(X_t,t)\,{\rm d}t+\sigma(X_t,t)\,{\rm d}W_t$, where $b$ and $\sigma$ are time-dependent.